# How to decide how many shuffles are done in an array?

Tags: java

I want my method to shuffle my array n<sup>2</sup> times if my array is of size n.

Here is my code:

```
public static void shuffle(String[] array){
  Random generator = new Random(12);
  for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {

  }
}
```

How do I add a line of code to specify how many shuffles I want to be done?

Comment: What does "shuffle my array n^4" mean? Do you mean swap n^4 elements?

Comment: Shuffle my elements n^4 times

Comment: So, for instance, if you have 100 elements in your array, you want to shuffle it 100000000 times?

Comment: And when you say "shuffle", you mean swapping two random elements like you show in your code, not an actual shuffle of the entire array, such as what `Collections.shuffle()` does?

Comment: Yes, two random elements from the array should be swapped.

Comment: Just for future reference, in Java `^` is the [bitwise exclusive OR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) operator, not exponentiation.  You'll confuse people if you try to use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

**Using single for loop**

```
public static void shuffle(char[] array){
     Random generator = new Random(12345);
          long numberOfShufflesMultiplier = (long)Math.pow(array.length,4); //your variable
           for (long i=0; i<numberOfShufflesMultiplier; i++) {
             int s = generator.nextInt(array.length);
             int index = (int)(i%array.length);
             char temp = array[index];
             array[index] = array[s];
             array[s] = temp;
           }
         }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be raised to the 4th power, not the 3rd?

Comment: The outer for loop takes care of that.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize at first you had nested loops.  Is there a reason you don't just use a simple for loop over the 4th power of the length instead?

Comment: I assumed the OP wanted each element in the array to be shuffled equally and not just the first one. If we use just one loop, it is possible that some positions might not get shuffled at all.

Comment: @Suraj Sorry, I'm new to this but what does the "j" represent?

Comment: @azurefrog Sorry, I take that back. We could do it with one loop too, I guess by using the modulus of division of the counter with the array length as the array index.

Comment: @AlexCabo "j" is just a counter to keep track of how many times an element at a particular position in the array gets shuffled.

Comment: Or just pick two random numbers.  It's mostly a matter of what's easier to read, and I personally find nested loops harder to follow. (as evidenced by the fact I didn't even see them at first glance... ;-)

Comment: How would I call this from the main method to check if it works?

Comment: Oh, also when using the power method, it told me there was an error due to trying to convert a double to long.

Comment: yep. Corrected that and added a way of doing it using a single for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Java collections framework has a [shuffling API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) that can shuffle any implementation of List interface.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
Random r = new Random(seed);
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
  Collections.shuffle(list, r);
}
```

After shuffling, you can convert the list to array using `list.toArray()`